# Need help in developing AWS IOT Based Mobile App

Tags: aws-iot, aws-mobilehub

I am a newbie in mobile development space, I am using aws iot cloud solution for one of my customers, I have to provision mobile app to my customer, which would list following tasks in it.
1) Login through facebook/google 
2) If devices are in more than one region show the option to choose those region 
3)List devices in the region
4) Get status of device
5) Publish message to Device

I am aware of AWs IOT, just need pointer in how should i go ahead in developing AWS IOT based mobile app.

Answer (score 2):

this is going to be a long answer hold on tight.

> Login in through Facebook/Google

Here you have two options either to use AWS Cognito or go for Independent Google/Facebook login. I opted for independent Google login as I found it easier for my mobile application. Also, in AWS Cognito I was not able to use the application when offline.

In the mobile hub, you can configure all settings for logins. Download the .JSON
and configure it with your application.

> List devices in the region

In order to do this, you need to make a database and store each user and their respective devices. Then query it in your application.

> Get status of device and Publishing

Here you need to Subscribe/Publish to your thing made in AWS IoT. Follow the exact steps given [here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/AndroidPubSub).  Now the sample that you read is for an Unauthenticated user, which you don't want. There are few more steps from now

1. Attach IoT policy to the Authenticated Pool.
2. Now each user needs to be attached a PrinciplePolicy. You can automate the process with Lambda function in AWS. The code is below:

'

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2))
    event.Records.forEach((record) => {
        console.log(record.eventName);
        if (record.eventName == "INSERT") {
            console.log('DynamoDB Record:', JSON.stringify(record));
            console.log('DynamoDB Record:', record.dynamodb['Keys']['UserId']['S']);
            var user = record.dynamodb['Keys']['UserId']['S'];
            const iotMgmt = new AWS.Iot();
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                let params = {
                    policyName: "basic",
                    principal: user
                };
                iotMgmt.attachPrincipalPolicy(params, (err, res) => {
                    console.log("Attaching IoT policy to " + user);
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                        reject(err);
                    }
                    else {
                        resolve();
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Since you are using Social logins you need to add the following code in your application for Facebook:

```
Map<String, String> logins = new HashMap<String, String>();
        logins.put("graph.facebook.com", AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getToken());
        credentialsProvider.setLogins(logins);
```

To get the changes to the shadow in the  application `$aws/things/thing_name/shadow/update/accepted`

And to publish the data to the shadow type `$aws/things/thing_name/shadow/update`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to take a look at the [aws-mobile-react-native-starter](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-mobile-react-native-starter).

Hope it helps.